# writing custom namespace IQ stanza in ejabberd using xmpp library

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have nearly updated ejabberd from 16.02 to 18.01. Main problem is that my module which i developed in older version is not working properly, because in older version of ejabberd wasn't using xmpp library (instead for that there was jlib), so iq record definition has changed.. i don't know how to add my custom namespace in xmpp library

Comment: it's not easy and it's boring, you should add new clause to xmpp_codec:get_mode/3 and add new module for decoding and encoding your xml.

Comment: yesterday i tried making my own xmpp spec..i registered my spec module with xmpp:register_code(conversation) but after restarting ejabberd there is a critical error

Comment: @BekaGelashvili I was working on a similar problem described here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208545/what-does-feature-not-implemented-response-mean] with my ejabberd iq handler module. Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom namespace by adding new plugin in eJabberd.

Please follow the step below:

1. Add your custom namespace in `jlib.hrl` with `define` macro.
2. Create a new plugin module in eJabberd which can refer `mod_ping`.
3. Modify  section `modules` of `ejabberd.cfg` to enable your plugin.

Please remember to register your plugin with `gen_iq_handler:add_iq_handler`, when your plugin is started.

If you want to add a feature which can be negotiated you must register your plugin with `mod_disco:register_feature`.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. i have done it as you described and my module worked perfectly.. (by the way jlib.hrl is depricated in newest ejabberd). i have to use xmpp instead of jlib, beacause i include some ejabberd hrls which therefore includes xmpp.hrl, so there is conflict between jlib.hrl and xmpp.hrl.